# Pandas Dataframes merging thru iterations. How to avoid lists and rows of headers

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I code just once in a while and I am super basic at the moment. Might be a silly question, but it got me stuck in for a bit too much now.

**Background**

I have a function (`get_profiles`) that plots points every 5m along one transect line (100m long) and extracts elevation (from a geotiff).
The arguments are:

- dsm (digital surface model)
- transect_file (geopackage, holds many LineStrings with different transect_ID)
- transect_id (int, extracted from transect_file)
- step (int, number of meters to extract elevation along transect lines)

The output for one transect line is a dataframe like in the picture, which is what I expected, and I like it!

[image]

However, the big issue is when I iterate the function over the `transect_ids` (the transect_files has 10 Shapely LineStrings), like this:

```
tr_list = np.arange(1,transect_file.shape[0]-1)  
geodb_transects= []
for i in tr_list:
        temp=get_profiles(dsm,transect_file,i,5)
        geodb_transects.append(temp)
```

I get a list. It might be here the error, but I don't know how to do in another way.

```
 type(geodb_transects)
 output:list
```

And, what's worse, I get headers (`distance, z, tr_id, date`) every time a new iteration starts.

[image]

How to get a clean pandas dataframe, just like the output of 1 iteration (20rows) but with all the tr_id chunks of 20row each aligned and without headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output is a `DataFrame` then you’re simply looking to concatenate the incremental DataFrame into some growing DataFrame.

It’s not the most efficient but something like

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame()
for i in range(7) :
    df = df.concat( df_ret_func(i))
```

You may also be interested in the `from_records` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) if you have a list of elements that are all records of the same form and can be converted into the rows of a DataFrame.

Comment: Thx a lot @jxramos! I guess I was using the wrong formula, List and .append, while the right one was Dataframe .concat !